# Django: Problems passing a list and the results of the list treated by a function as two separate variables to the template

Tags: django, django-views, django-templates

I'm trying to make CV website which has a sudoku generator and solver. The generator and solver are two separate functions in the functions.py file imported into the views.py file.
My sudokus are stored in a list of 9 lists of 9 ints.

from views.py:

```
from functions import *

def sudoku(request):
    grid = make_sudoku() # generates unsolved sudoku list
    solved = solve(grid) # generates solved list of unsolved list fed in.
    count = [i for i in range(9)]
    context = {
        'grid': grid,
        'solved': solved,
        'count': count
        }
    return render(request, 'main/sudoku.html', context)
```

if I print grid, I get an unsolved sudoku list. If I print solved, I get a the same list which has been solved. Everything works dandy up until that point, but if I go to sudoku.html and type {{ grid }}, I get a solved sudoku list.

As the tree said to the lumberjack, I'm STUMPED! I'm completely baffled as to why this might happen because at no point in sudoku.html do I refer to grid or solved outside of passing them on to sudoku.js which actually makes the puzzle.

Answer (score 0):

your `solve()` function probably is not only returning the solved `grid` but it'd also modify the existing grid and solve it in place, it's not making a copy but solving it on the same grid. read more about passing by value and passing by reference (here `grid` is being passes by reference)

https://flexiple.com/python/python-pass-by-reference/

additionally, you can replace

```py
count = [i for i in range(9)]
```

by

```py
count = list(range(9))
```